# Importing functions in python 3

Tags: import, python-3.4, function

I am learning some more advanced functions of python and I was wondering if it is possible to use a function in one program and import it to another program and use the same functions.

for example:

script1.py

```
def EX():
print('example')
```

script2.py

```
import script1.py
EX()
```

Thank you if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the syntax is:

script1.py:

```
def EX():
    print('example')
```

script2.py:

```
import script1
EX()
```